Inotify watch descriptors leak in Ubuntu 24.04
I have a program that walks recursively over a big filesystem, and it put watch descriptors in every folder and file.
Previously, this program ran on centos 7 and it worked like a charm, but in Ubuntu 24.04, it looks like when I kill gracefully the process, which creates the watch descriptors, they aren't getting freed and a lot of memory is still being "used", probably by the kernel.
Does somebody knows something about it or have an idea what can be done?
